# Why does the composition/frame of a design looks distorted sometimes?

Tags: interface-design, design-principles

Sometimes, when I work on some designs, the everything looks fine except the overall *frame* (I don't know how should I describe it).

For example, see these 2 designs:

[image]
[image]

And here is how I see them overall, respectively:

[image]

I don't think it's just with me. Something must be there, because it happens sometimes, not every time.

So what's the basic reason of it? And what things one should keep in mind while designing so that such things do not happen?

Comment: I don't see those perspective shifts at all.

Comment: I don't know why, but I always see them when something is *wrong* in design. Because in well designed things (like billboards, ads of big companies) I never notice such things. I notice this in some entry level designs mostly.

Comment: I think that's an awesome question and psychology of perception can help us answer this. It's definitely not opinion based

Comment: The first image is extremely poorly balanced apart from having all the elements bad arranged: the perspective of the table points to the sky, the shadows go in any direction, there is no matching structural line. In particular, I would not choose it as an example at all.

Comment: @Danielillo you just *blasted* my design! :D I also need such experience. How many years it take?

Comment: I didn't know it was your design, anyway it has a lot of mistakes. Just have a look to your other questions/answers about the same kind of things and try to follow them.

Comment: Not meaning to be flippant... but seriously, when was the last time you had your vision checked? The trapezoidal distortion you are outlining is a *common* occurrence for someone with an astigmatism.

Comment: .. and ya missed a spot on the mask of the guy's photo between his back and the hole in the chair... :)

Comment: @Scott astigmatism causes blurred vision?

Comment: @Danielillo don't think I don't follow *your* rules. See the 2nd image. I somehow tried to maintain a clock wise *rotation*, as you mentioned in some of your answers ;)

Comment: @Scott also Scott, if I had that problem, I would also assume about the designs on Behance, and Dribble. But I never found something like that. I seriously don't think it's a disease. But yes, it can be an optical illusion.

Comment: Astigmatism causes squares to *not* look like squares. It has actually little to do with "blurred vision".

Comment: @Scott okay. But I don't notice it in designers who make good designs. Like I never noticed something like this in designs on Behance and Dribbble. I either notice it in my designs or a beginner's designs. And I see a square perfectly square.

Comment: Also, if you give me thousand squares on a screen, some with noticeably distortions, I will identify which are more closer to perfect square. So clearly my question has something to do with. Either it is just because I have an artistic mind or there is some optical illusion.

Comment: I have a self made answer. I don't have a strong reason or reference, but can't share because since all seem against here, I may get pretty heavy down votes.

Comment: @Vikas post your answer and leave the question open, maybe someone comes up with a different answer. Don't worry about downvotes.

Comment: @Luciano good idea